# how to push html php content inside a class

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, opencart

I have a website build in opencart, I am trying to add an HTML PHP content in a section in homepage, when I opened the editor, I couldn't see the code for the section, all I have is the class of the section, so I  tried to add it using like below:

```css
.menu-mobile:before {
    content:"<div class='block block-currency;'><?php echo $currency; ?></div>";
}
```

But then I found out that it's not possible to add HTML PHP content inside this css attribute. can anyone please tell me is there anyway to push HTML PHP content inside a class using javascript or any other way, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide us with DOM structure? That'd be helpful

Comment: "not possible" means what? Do you get a specific error or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP code works only in .php extension file. so you can not print PHP code in the CSS file. for your solution, you have to mention inline CSS on the PHP file. and also the content is used for text only. you can not use HTML on this content

```
<style type="text/css">
    .menu-mobile:before{
        content:"<?php echo $currency; ?>";
        /*your css code*/
    }
</style>
```

Comment: sorry, i didnt get you, (my style is in PHP file only)

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side language while CSS is a client side. If you're inserting php code into a web page with css you're going to see the php code itself, and not the data that the php code would output.